# Using CKAsset to store API JSON and Updating every 6 Hours

Tags: json, swift, api, cloudkit, ckasset

I'm building a native iOS app with Swift/Xcode that utilizes JOSN data from a 3rd party API. Everything is working fine but the API has restrictions on the number of calls you can make to the API each hour. So now I'm building a function intended to create a weekly database as a CK Asset in CloudKit which will update the JSON from the API every 6 hours. This way the data is still relatively current but also reduces the number of API calls to just 4 a day.

Note: The app is being tested in Production/TestFlight.

The function is working correctly when creating a new CKAsset to save as a new CKRecord in CloudKit. The function also correctly downloads and decodes the CKAsset from CloudKit for use in the app. <- And anyone is able to download this asset and it works just fine.

The issue: Whenever the function checks if the CKAsset is more than 6 hours old, it is supposed to let any user modify the CKRecord by downloading a newer JSON file and replacing it in the CKAsset of the CKRecord using the CKModifyRecordsOperation. The problem is, whenever another user tries to modify the record the app crashes.

Question: Why can't any other users using TestFlight modify the record? Am I wrong to use CKModifyRecordsOperation?

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

-------------------------------CODE/FUNC--------------------------------

```
func fetchWeeklyPlayersDB() {
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 0)
let thisWeek = getCurrentWeekID()
let current = Date()

// fetch current week PlayersDB from CK Database
publicDB.fetch(withRecordID: CKRecord.ID(recordName:thisWeek + "_Players"))  { record, error in
    // process record
    if let r = record { // we know the playersDB has data
        let modified = r.modificationDate
        let expirationDate = modified?.addingTimeInterval(6*60*60) // add 6 hours
        // if CK DB expirationDate is less than now, use it
        if expirationDate! > current {
            // not outdated - just process
            if let data = r["DB"] {
                // decode the JSON and set it to rawData
                let d = readCKAsset(asset: data as! CKAsset)
                let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(dfsAPIData.self, from: d as! Data)
                rawData = result
                semaphore.signal()
            }
            
        } else { // CK DB is more than 6 hours old, call api and overwite data
            // call API
            let apiData = callAPI(week: findWeek())

            // encode the api data as NSData
            let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
            do {
                let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(apiData)
                // save data locally
                if let path = saveJSON(data: jsonData) {
                    // convert result to CKASset using local save filepath
                    let asset:CKAsset = CKAsset.init(fileURL: path)
                    r["DB"] = asset
                    // Modify PlayersDB value in CKRecord
                    let modifyRecord = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [r], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
                    modifyRecord.savePolicy = CKModifyRecordsOperation.RecordSavePolicy.allKeys
                    modifyRecord.qualityOfService = QualityOfService.userInitiated
                    modifyRecord.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in
                        if error == nil {
                            // we did it!
                            print("PlayersDB Successfully overwritted with update api data")
                            // delete the file you created
                            deleteJSON(path: path)
                            rawData = apiData
                            semaphore.signal()
                        } else {
                            print("ERROR SAVING PlayersDB TO CK" + error!.localizedDescription)
                            // delete the file you created
                            deleteJSON(path: path)
                            // pull from the CK DB anyway so it fails softly
                            if let data = r["DB"] {
                                // decode the JSON and set it to rawData
                                let d = readCKAsset(asset: data as! CKAsset)
                                let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(dfsAPIData.self, from: d as! Data)
                                rawData = result
                                semaphore.signal()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    publicDB.add(modifyRecord)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error Encoding JSON - WTF")
                // if encoding fails - pull latest db instead to fail softly
                if let data = r["DB"] {
                    // decode the JSON and set it to rawData
                    let d = readCKAsset(asset: data as! CKAsset)
                    let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(dfsAPIData.self, from: d as! Data)
                    rawData = result
                    semaphore.signal()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // process error - DB doesnt exist, Call API and Create It
    if let e = error {
        // call API
        let apiData = callAPI(week: findWeek())
        // create record
        let recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName:thisWeek + "_Players")
        let record = CKRecord(recordType: "WeeklyDB", recordID: recordID)
        // encode the api data as NSData
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(apiData)
            if let path = saveJSON(data: jsonData) {
                // convert result to CKASset using local save filepath
                let asset:CKAsset = CKAsset.init(fileURL: path)
                record["DB"] = asset
                    // Save DB to CK
                    publicDB.save(record, completionHandler: {returnRecord, error in
                        if let err = error {
                            // something happened
                            print("ERROR SAVING PlayersDB TO CK" + err.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            // we did it!
                            print("PlayersDB Successfully overwritted with update api data")
                            // delete the file you just created
                            deleteJSON(path: path)
                            rawData = apiData
                            semaphore.signal()
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error Encoding JSON while saving api data to PlayersDB - WTF")
        }
    }
}
semaphore.wait()
return
```

}

Comment: If somebody says their app crashes, wouldn't you ask "at what line"?

Comment: ... and with what error.

Comment: just a few coding tips; the JSON can be stored as a string. No need to dump to files and use CKAsset. Also, your update code should not exist inside a fetch function. Do your fetch, when it comes back, update as necessary in separate code.

Comment: Thanks @johnelemans! I appreciate the feedback. I'll rework the code to separate out the fetch and update functions. When I initially created the function I was using the Bytes datatype in CK and I ran into an error saying the memory limit of 1MB was exceeded. So instead I switched it to CKAsset to provide myself with the largest memory limit to stay within. Does the String Datatype in CK have a similar limit to the Bytes datatype or is it larger? My JSON files are usually between 1-2mb.

Comment: You are right, you need to use CKAsset for records over 1MB.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution to this answer comes in three parts because there were essentially three issues I was encountering.

One - When I first created my function I was using the CK datatype "Bytes" and "String" to save my JSON, but I was getting an error because the size of my JSON was over the 1mb limit those datatypes conform to. I didn't realize the size limit was causing the error, instead I thought it was the Save feature that was not working, so I switched to using the CKModifyRecord to try saving. Once that failed I noticed the size limit and switched to using CKAsset to save the database. This fixed the limit, but I still received errors when either saving or modifying the asset of the CK record.

Two - Since size was no longer the issue, I did some digging and it turns out security permissions in CloudKit was denying other users from saving a record they didn't create. To fix this I went into CK Dashboard and found the "Security Roles" under the "Schema" section. I switched the roles from "Creator" to "iCloud" to allow all connected iCloud users to edit records.

Three - The final problem I had was with identifying the errors I was getting from my TestFlight Testers. Until this point I had never tried to access the Crash Logs from TestFlight users and I though it was a long and convoluted process. Nope - its built into Xcode out of the box, not configuration required.
(1) With Xcode open, click on Window > Organizer in the top menu to open the Organizer Window.

[image]

(2) From here you can see all crash logs from each build you've archived and submitted to test flight. And, you can even run them in Xcode to find the line/error that crashed the program by clicking "Open in Xcode" button.

[image]